# Make lightning:datatable horizontally scrollable

Tags: lightning-datatable

I have a datatable that can potentially have tons of column, placed inside a limited area.

How can I make it horizontally scrollable?

I've tried wrapping parent container into `class="slds-scrollable_x"` to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Columns have a `minColumnWidth` property. You can set the column min to something you choose (perhaps something that lets you read the title properly). If the added widths of the columns exceed the component's screen size, then the horizontal scroll bar will appear.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm) states the following:

> **Resizing Tables and Columns**
>
> The width and height of the datatable is determined by the container
>   element. A scroller is appended to the table body if there are more
>   rows to display. For example, you can restrict the height to 300px by
>   applying CSS styling to the container element.

So, if you set a specific width to the container element, then, my understanding is that the scroller should be appended automatically.

For example:

```
<div style="width: 300px;">
    <!-- lightning:datatable goes here -->
</div>
```

Tested and Works...

[image]

```
  <div class="container" style="width:250px">
        <lightning:datatable data="{! v.mydata }" 
            columns="{! v.mycolumns }" 
            keyField="id"
            onrowselection="{! c.getSelectedName }"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: That seems to work only with the height

Comment: works for the width as well

Comment: Yeah, but whats the use of it when headers are unreadable?

Comment: you can modify taht with css, the above is just for reference purposes

Comment: Also, what is the right way to use it with slds grid? Hardcoding pixel values  won't fly.

Comment: that itself is a completely different question =P, but I agree, having to do this is kind of a pain. Another reason why using build in components can sometimes be tedious

Comment: Columns have a `minColumnWidth` property. Have you explored with setting that min width and seeing if the datatable figures out scrolling on its own (i.e. if the width of all the columns exceeds the component)?

Comment: @SebastianKessel yeah that solved it. Worth noting that it's a plain integer, rather than px.

Comment: I'll post as an answer, so others can benefit.

Comment: Note that wrapping lightning-datatable in a DIV with a large width has the effect that the column headers are no longer sticky.  If the table has lots of rows, and the user scrolls down vertically, the column headers are no longer visible.  I recommend using column with attributes instead to achieve horizontal scrolling and make column headers remain sticky.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a good experience embedding my `lighting-datatable` inside a `lightning-layout-item` with a `size` property declared to an appropriate integer value (size corresponds to their Design System grid layout and can be 1 through 12)

```xml
<lightning-layout style="height:600px">
        <lightning-layout-item size=12>
           
            <lightning-datatable
                    if:true={data}
                    key-field={keyInfo.KeyName}
                    data={data}
                    columns={columns}
                 
                    >
            </lightning-datatable>
        </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>
```

I also restrict the height at the outer `lighting-layout` level.

All scrollbars seem to appear as they should: when needed, and disappear when not needed. And not at the expense of losing the column headers when scrolling through long resuls